# CKEditor ShowProtected moves handlebars code

Tags: ckeditor, handlebars.js, ckeditor4.x

If you are using CKEditor with handlebars code, you can mark handlebars code as protected using

```
config.protectedSource.push(/{{[/|#][\s\S]*?}}/g);
```

This works well but hides the handlebars code in the main WYSIWYG editor.

The showprotected plugin (https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/showprotected) can then be used to display an icon whenever there is handlebars code.

But, if you have code like

```
<ul>
  {{#each Books}}
    <li>{{Title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

the CKEditor changes the HTML into this:

```
{{#each Books}}{{/each}}
<ul>
    <li>{{Title}}</li>
</ul>
```

I have set

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

but this does not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the [CKEditor DTD](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dtd.html) which controls how HTML elements are allowed to be nested.

When the CKEditor displays in WYSIWYG mode, the [showprotected](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/showprotected) plugin displays a small icon instead of the handlebars code.  This effectively creates the following html:

```
<ul>
  <img class='cke_protected'..../>
    <li>{{Title}}</li>
  <img class='cke_protected'..../>
</ul>
```

Images are not allowed to be placed directly inside UL tags and so CKEditor rearranges it into

```
<img class='cke_protected'..../><img class='cke_protected'..../>
<ul>
    <li>{{Title}}</li>
</ul>
```

You can fix this problem by telling the DTD that image tags are allowed inside the UL tags

```
CKEDITOR.dtd['ul']['img'] = true;
```